# Is there a way to append NaT to a pandas datetime with timezone without changing dtype to object?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a column in my DataFrame that is dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]. When I append a row with either None or NaT in that column, the dtype of the column changes to 'object'. This does not happen to columns that are dtype: datetime64[ns].

Here is a demonstration:

```
# Test pandas with datetime columns
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timezone
df = pd.DataFrame([{'D': datetime.utcnow()}])
df_wtz = pd.DataFrame([{'D': datetime.now().astimezone(timezone.utc)}])
df_None = pd.DataFrame([{'D': None}])
# Note that the tz below is ignored even though specified
df_Nat = pd.DataFrame([{'D': pd.Timestamp(None,tz=timezone.utc)}])

print('df:\n', df['D'])
print('df_wtz:\n', df_wtz['D'])
print('df_None:\n', df_None['D'])
print('df_Nat:\n', df_Nat['D'])

print('df append df_None:\n', df.append(df_None, ignore_index=True, sort=False)['D'])
print('df append df_Nat:\n', df.append(df_Nat, ignore_index=True, sort=False)['D'])

print('df_wtz append df_None:\n', df_wtz.append(df_None, ignore_index=True, sort=False)['D'])
print('df_wtz append df_Nat:\n', df_wtz.append(df_Nat, ignore_index=True, sort=False)['D'])
```

Here is the output:

```
df:
 0   2019-08-13 19:58:18.811492
Name: D, dtype: datetime64[ns]
df_wtz:
 0   2019-08-13 19:58:18.811968+00:00
Name: D, **dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]**
df_None:
 0    None
Name: D, dtype: object
df_Nat:
 0   NaT
Name: D, dtype: datetime64[ns]
df append df_None:
 0   2019-08-13 19:58:18.811492
1                          NaT
Name: D, dtype: datetime64[ns]
df append df_Nat:
 0   2019-08-13 19:58:18.811492
1                          NaT
Name: D, dtype: datetime64[ns]
df_wtz append df_None:
 0    2019-08-13 19:58:18.811968+00:00
1                                None
Name: D, dtype: object
df_wtz append df_Nat:
 0    2019-08-13 19:58:18.811968+00:00
1                                 NaT
Name: D, dtype: object
```

I had expected the column type to be retained in the case of appending None or NaT to the datetime64[ns, UTC] column but it is not. Is this the intended behavior or would this be considered a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a NaT in a column with dtype `datetime64[ns, UTC]` this way:

```
 In [380]: df_Nat = pd.DataFrame({'D': pd.to_datetime([None], utc=True)}); df_Nat
 Out[380]: 
     D
 0 NaT

 In [381]: df_Nat.info()
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
 Data columns (total 1 columns):
 D    0 non-null datetime64[ns, UTC]
 dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1)
 memory usage: 88.0 bytes
```

Appending `df_Nat` to `df_wtz` now preserves the dtype:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
utc = DT.timezone.utc
now = DT.datetime.now()
df_wtz = pd.DataFrame([{'D': now.astimezone(utc)}])
df_Nat = pd.DataFrame({'D': pd.to_datetime([None], utc=True)})
# df_Nat = pd.DataFrame({'D':pd.Series(pd.NaT, dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]')}) # also works

print('df_wtz append df_Nat:\n', df_wtz.append(df_Nat, ignore_index=True, sort=False)['D'])
```

yields

```
df_wtz append df_Nat:
 0   2019-08-13 20:28:15.928023+00:00
1                                NaT
Name: D, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

---

The NaT itself is not timezone aware:

```
In [383]: pd.Timestamp(None) is pd.Timestamp(None, tz=utc)
Out[383]: True
```

So `pd.DataFrame([{'D': pd.Timestamp(None,tz=utc)}])` does not produce a column with timezone-aware dtype.

Since it is impossible to make the DataFrame infer a timezone-aware dtype from the NaT itself,
we need to build a container (such as a Series or DatetimeIndex) which already has the right timezone-aware dtype. That is what `pd.to_datetime([None], utc=True)` does:

```
In [385]: pd.to_datetime([None], utc=True)
Out[385]: DatetimeIndex(['NaT'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks - this will work for me. I still rather regret that appending a None modifies the column type though...